# Java cloning and clone method working

Tags: java, object, deep-copy, cloning, notsupportedexception

I'm new to java and I was trying to figure out how cloning works in java during my search operation I stumbled upon a program code for deep cloning but I don't have any clue if this program is write or wrong so pls help me.. This is the code...

My question is that can we implement this  protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException in two different classes ?? If yes then why we're doing this ?? Pls answer as simple as you can... Thanks in advance...

PS: This is my first question here. So pls bear with me....

```
class A implements Cloneable
{
    int i;

    public A(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

class B implements Cloneable
{
    int j;

    A a;

    public B(int j, A a)
    {
        this.j = j;

        this.a = a;
    }

        //Overriding clone method to implement deep copy

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        B b = (B) super.clone();

        b.a = (A) a.clone();

        return b;
    }
}

public class CloneMethodDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       A a = new A(10);

       B b1 = new B(20, a);

       B b2 = null;

       try
       {
           //Creating clone of b1 and assigning it to b2

            b2 = (B) b1.clone();
       }
       catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
       {
           System.out.println("Onject is not clone-able");
       }

       //Printing value of b1.a.i

       System.out.println(b1.a.i);        //Output : 10

       //Changing the value of b2.a.i to 100

       b2.a.i = 100;

       //Now, this change will not effect the original object

       System.out.println(b1.a.i);         //Output : 10
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: what do you mean by-->My question is that can we implement this protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException in two different classes ?? If yes then why we're doing this ?? Pls answer as simple as you can

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience....

Comment: As you can see that Class A and Class B both are implementing the clone method. So I just wanted to know is that even possible ??

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Did you test it?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand the whole concept... Why we need to implement two Cloneable interface ??

Comment: `A` and `B` are in no way related

Comment: So we can implement this Cloneable interface in as many class as we want ??

Comment: Yes, an interface is meant to be implemented by several classes providing the same set of methods.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking such silly questions but still I have alot of confusion related with cloning...

Comment: It's probably best that you forget about cloning altogether, it's kind of a dead end design decision in early Java that has several severe drawbacks. Check out "Effective Java" for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: "Can I paint both the chair and the table red?" "Yes." "So I can use the color red on any furniture?" "Yes." "Why would I do that if I want everything to be red?" That's the point where we get difficulty following your train of thought.

Comment: Thanks alot! all of you guys for the explanation....